# Can I extend my Windows display to another Windows 10 laptop via cable?

Tags: windows-10, display

Is there a way I can extend my Windows Display to another Windows Laptop via a USB cable, etc.?

I know I can't use an HDMI port on the receiving laptop b/c that's an "out" only. I'm hoping that I can maybe use the USB as the input on the receiving end.

Comment: The ability entirely depends on the hardware.  However, those features that do exist (for example Thunderbolt), that supports connecting an external display over USB, are limited by the same restrictions has HDMI.  Update your question to properly identify your hardware so a relevant answer can be submitted.  Thunderbolt and USB 3.1. Gen 2 cannot be used to turn a tablet into an external display for another device (for the same reasons the HDMI port cannot be used).  Please edit your question so it can be answered

Comment: Would a 'Remote Desktop' connection (or VNC) via your network count as a solution?